# What values are given for the `os.name` family of functions on various platforms in Python?

Tags: python

Python has a handful of different ways to determine what OS the program is running on:

- `os.name`
- `platform.system()`
- `sys.platform`

What are the values of these on various platforms?

Comment: `os.uname()` is also pretty interesting. 151 characters, in 5 separate strings on my Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.name
'posix'
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Linux'
>>> import sys
>>> sys.platform
'linux2'
```

Mac OS:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.name
'posix'
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Darwin'
>>> import sys
>>> sys.platform
'darwin'
```

Windows:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.name
'nt'
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Windows'
>>> import sys
>>> sys.platform
'win32'
```

Cygwin:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.name
'posix'
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'CYGWIN_NT-10.0'
>>> import sys
>>> sys.platform
'cygwin'
```

Comment: Presumably `sys.platform` might be `linux3` or `linux4` for later kernel versions? Not going to swear to that (can't test right now).

Comment: This was on a 4.17 kernel (modern Debian machine). I think the Python devs decided it wouldn't be a good idea to keep revving that number since it would probably break a lot of code. Probably still wise to write that check as `sys.platform.startswith('linux')` just in case.

Comment: It's not as simple as "these values for Linux, these values for Mac OS, these values for Windows, these values for Cygwin". For example, `sys.platform` depends on your Python version, and on the platform version when Python was *built*.

Comment: It's a wiki answer. Can you add some examples showing what you're describing?

Comment: On Linux, on Python 2.7, `sys.platform` will be `'linux2'`. On Linux, on Python 3.3+, `sys.platform` will be `'linux'`. On Linux, on other Python versions, `sys.platform` could be something like `'linux3'` or `'linux4'`.

Comment: On my Mac, I get the same values for all three under 2.7 and 3.6.5.